# np.arrayから、削除する要素をnp.arrayで指定したい

Tags: python, numpy

以下のようなことがしたいです。

```
a = np.array([3, 5])
b = np.array([2, 0, 4, 5, 1, 3])
```

のときに、aで指定した[3, 5]をbから削除して
`np.array([2, 0, 4, 1])`
を取得したいです。

現状、恥ずかしながら以下のようなかなり冗長なコードになってしまっています。

```
a_indices = np.where(np.any(np.array([b == e for e in a]).T, axis = 1))[0]
c = np.delete(b, a_indices)
```

簡潔に書く方法があればご教授ください。

Comment: `np.setdiff1d(b, a)` とすると良いかと思いますが、結果はソートされたものになります（`array([0, 1, 2, 4])` ）。配列の要素の順序を保持したい場合は `b[~np.in1d(b, a)]` でしょうかね。

Comment: 関連: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46261671/use-numpy-setdiff1d-keeping-the-order やはり`b[~np.in1d(b,a)]`ですかね

Comment: @metropolis さん、user10685 さん、解決策は回答としてご投稿頂けませんでしょうか？　よろしくお願いいたします<(\_ \_)>